# Conclusions from combination of P value and Effect size

Tags: bayesian, p-value, effect-size

Limitations of P values are being increasingly highlighted in recent literature (e.g. [here](https://scientificallysound.org/2016/03/31/the-limitations-of-p-values/) and [here](http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/EP/EP713_RandomError/EP713_RandomError7.html)). To evaluate results of unpaired t-test, following is an approach combining P values and [effect size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size):

[image]

Which of these conclusions are ***most vulnerable*** to limitations of P value and hypothesis testing and which of these are least likely to be incorrect? Also, for which of these situations, Bayesian analysis/Bayes Factors have distinct advantages over hypothesis testing? Thanks for your insight.

**Edit:** 
Following algorithm adds `power` assessment if P>0.05:

[image]

Codes at end of conclusions are as follows: SDL- small difference likely; MDL-moderate difference likely; LDL- large difference likely; SDVL- small difference very likely; MDVL- moderate difference very likely; LDVL- large difference very likely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow chart conflates two things: 
Size of difference and significance of difference.

The bottom line is factually correct, at least if you adapt 0.05 as a cutoff. But the problem is that that conclusion doesn't answer the question about the size of the difference. For that, you need an effect size measure (such as d) and its standard error.

Further, in many areas, we start off knowing that the null is false with a high degree of certainty.

And all of the cutoffs in your diagram are arbitrary.  Why is d = 0.51 "moderate" while d = 0.49 is "small"?  The same d might be very important in one area and not at all important in another.

One example where a very small effect size is very important is in airplane safety.  A plane that crashes on 1 in 1,000 flights is very, very bad. But 1 in 1,000 is a very small effect.